# how to fill nan values based on conditions in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, dataframe

I am working on the Titanic dataset and there are null values in the `Age` column. I would like to fill them in based on there Pclass.

For example, if class is 1, I will fill with the mean of all passengers whose class is 1.
I have found all the means, but I cannot figure out how to fill age column with conditions.

Comment: please provide with the snapshot or link to the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(df.groupby('Pclass')['Age'].transform('mean'))`